# How to simplify the inverse $(AB)^{-1}$ for rectangular $A$ and $B$?

Tags: matrices, inverse

Assume real rectangular matrices $A$ and $B$, where $A$ is $m \times n$, $B$ is $n \times m$, $m<n$, and the $m \times m$ product $AB$ is invertible. What are some possible strategies for simplifying the expression for the inverse $(AB)^{-1}$?

For example, the [Cauchy-Binet formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Binet_formula) provides an expression for $\det(AB)$ as a sum of products of simpler determinants. Is there a related formula for the inverse?

Are there more options available if we further assume that $AB=B^T B$? Or additionally that $AB=B^T B$ is a [Gramian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gramian_matrix)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Cramer's Rule, $(AB)^{-1}_{ij} = (-1)^{i+j}\det(M_{ji})/\det(AB)$ where $M_{ji}$ is the matrix obtained by removing the $j$'th row and $i$'th column of $AB$. Thus $M_{ji} = A_j B_i$ where  $A_j$ is obtained by removing the $j$'th row from $A$ and $B_i$ is obtained by removing the $i$'th column from $B$.  You can then apply Cauchy-Binet to $\det(A_j B_i)$.

Comment: I had just started looking into approaches based on $X^{-1} = \operatorname{adj}(X)/\det(X)$ and came back here to post an update when I noticed your nice, detailed response. Thank you!